# Xcode 9.2: missing required architecture arm64 in file /......../libPaymentsSDK.a (2 slices)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, arm64, paytm

I am implementing PayTm PayTm payment gateway into my app. On simulator it works fine but when i tried to install it on device it shows error.
I am sharing error details please suggest some solution

> warning: ignoring file /Users/..../libPaymentsSDK.a, missing required
>   architecture arm64 in file /Users/..../libPaymentsSDK.a (2 slices)
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PGTransactionViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in SubscribeMagzineVC.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PGOrder", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in SubscribeMagzineVC.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PGMerchantConfiguration", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in SubscribeMagzineVC.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image]

> Architectures in the fat file: /Users/.../libPaymentsSDK.a are: armv7
>   i386 x86_64 arm64

[image]

Comment: 1. can you share screen shot linked libraries? 2. Have you enabled bitcode?

Comment: check updated ques. where to enable bitcode?

Comment: You can find it under Build Settings-> Build Options -> Enable Bitcode

Comment: yes i enable but not working

Comment: Disable bitcode and try it.

Comment: let me know which SDK you are using in your project?. You can find the different sdk here: https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_iOS_App_Kit

Comment: disable it not working and also using the same sdk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163327/discussion-between-arasuvel-and-abhinandan-pratap).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like `libPaymentsSDK.a` has 2 slices and my guess they're `i386` and `x86_64`, `arm64` is probably not one of them, first you can check which slices are there by running

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info libPaymentsSDK.a
```

You basically need to rebuild `libPaymentsSDK` with `arm64` support too.

The best way I would recommend is to integrated it with Cocoapods into your projects, then everything will build properly, if you don't want to do that, simply rebuild the `libPaymentsSDK` yourself but make sure arm64 is present.

An easier way is to just use the provided one from the SDK found [here](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_iOS_App_Kit/raw/master/Paytm/libPaymentsSDK.a) simply download and replace your old one with that file

To use the `lipo` command you simply need to open `terminal.app` and then 
find the exact location of the `libPaymentSDK.a` file, you can do that by going into xcode, selecting the file from the left pane, then on the right pane you will see the file details in the file inspector, just copy it's path, it'll be something like:

```
/Users/myUsername/Projects/exampleAPP/myAppLibs/libPaymentSDK.a
```

Then you simply add that path to the end of the command to be:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info /Users/myUsername/Projects/exampleAPP/myAppLibs/libPaymentSDK.a
```

Hope this solves your issue, good luck!

Comment: not working :( i download it and replace with old file but issue remains same

Comment: how to run this script xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info libPaymentsSDK.a

Comment: That is strange it should work, maybe you need to clean your build ?, i'll update my answer to show how to run the command

Comment: terminal shows the following details: libPaymentsSDK.a are: armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64

Comment: Did you Clean and rebuild ? Also clean derived data just in case

Comment: Arch in fat file: libPaymentsSDK.a are: armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64     and  error is: missing required architecture arm64 in file

Comment: It is the new error: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163399/discussion-between-mostafa-torbjorn-berg-and-abhinandan-pratap).